# How can I test my web pages in various browsers like IE8 and older?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

Recently i am working on Chrome with windows7 OS installed. Bt win7 dsnt support Internet Explorer 8. So Im facing problem to view my created web pages to the IE8 version and older. How can I solve this problem?

And I have tried it from Developers tool/ inspecting element/ pressing F12 ... Nothing Im able to find about it . Help plz

Comment: Have you considered using a [virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine)?

Comment: IE contains older rendering engines (up to 7 IIRC). It's under the dev tools somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tried-and-true method is to set up virtual machines that have the actual OS and browser installed on them.

See: http://joemaller.com/2896/ie6-ie7-and-ie8-compatibility-testing-with-microsoft-virtual-pcs/

And: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2013/04/02/new-on-modern-ie-free-vm-downloads-windows-8-quickstart-kits-enhanced-code-scanning-tools-and-more.aspx